# Vectorizing structure field access (or modify) matlab? Is it even possible?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization, variable-assignment, matlab-struct

After years of anonymity I've just created my account to ask a question which has been bugging me for a while and I just can't seem to find an answer. I really, really tried! Here it goes:

If you have the matlab structure array:

```
something(1).toSay = 'qwe';

something(2).toSay = 'asd';

something(3).toSay = 'zxc';
```

Is there any way to vectorize the reassignment of these 3 entries of the field `toSay`?

Like

```
something = magicFunction(something, [1:3], 'toSay', {'newString1','newString2','newString3'})
```

final results being:

```
something(2).toSay >> 'newString2'
```

I've tried something along with the `setfield` function, but couldn't make it work. All I'm trying to do with this question is avoid a *for-loop*.

Question 2: Would it make a difference if it was a cell array of structures and not a structure array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your replacement strings within a cell array and then use `{:}` indexing to create a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) on the right-hand side of the assignment. On the left-hand side, `something(1:3).toSay` already creates a comma separated list so we can enclose it in `[]` to assign the values on the right to their corresponding fields on the left.

```
newvalues = {'newString1', 'newString2', 'newString3'};
[something(1:3).toSay] = newvalues{:};
```

See: [Assigning output from a comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-7) and [Assigning to a comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-8)

With respect to your second question, making it a cell array of structs will require an additional step as you can't create a comma separated list directly when the structs are within a cell array. You'd have to first convert them to a struct array

```
sarray = [something{1:3}];
[sarray.toSay] = newValues{:};
something(1:3) = num2cell(sarray);
```